# Falha ao startar TomCat

Tags: aplicação-web, java-ee, eclipse, tomcat, catalina

Quando tento iniciar o `TomCat 7` no meu projeto chamado `ribeiraoreefshop`, dispara o erro de `start` o principal seria o seguinte:

> Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ribeiraoreefshop]

Abaixo o console de erro de start do TomCat que dispara.

> mai 21, 2018 6:26:41 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
>   ADVERTÊNCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ribeiraoreefshop' did not find a matching property.
>   mai 21, 2018 6:26:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFORMAÇÕES: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.85
>   mai 21, 2018 6:26:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFORMAÇÕES: Server built:          Feb 7 2018 18:52:33 UTC
>   mai 21, 2018 6:26:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFORMAÇÕES: Server number:         7.0.85.0
>   mai 21, 2018 6:26:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFORMAÇÕES: OS Name:               Windows 8.1
>   mai 21, 2018 6:26:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFORMAÇÕES: OS Version:            6.3
>   mai 21, 2018 6:26:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFORMAÇÕES: Architecture:          amd64
>   mai 21, 2018 6:26:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFORMAÇÕES: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_172
>   mai 21, 2018 6:26:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Version:           1.8.0_172-b11
>   mai 21, 2018 6:26:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
>   mai 21, 2018 6:26:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Tiago\workspaceTiago.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
>   mai 21, 2018 6:26:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
>   mai 21, 2018 6:26:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Tiago\workspaceTiago.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
>   mai 21, 2018 6:26:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
>   mai 21, 2018 6:26:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Tiago\workspaceTiago.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
>   mai 21, 2018 6:26:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed
>   mai 21, 2018 6:26:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
>   mai 21, 2018 6:26:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
>   INFORMAÇÕES: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_172\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_172/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_172/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_172/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Users\Tiago\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\Tiago\Desktop\eclipse;;.
>   mai 21, 2018 6:26:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
>   INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
>   mai 21, 2018 6:26:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
>   INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
>   mai 21, 2018 6:26:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
>   INFORMAÇÕES: Initialization processed in 6246 ms
>   mai 21, 2018 6:26:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
>   INFORMAÇÕES: Starting service Catalina
>   mai 21, 2018 6:26:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
>   INFORMAÇÕES: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.85
>   mai 21, 2018 6:26:50 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
>   ADVERTÊNCIA: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [2,961] milliseconds.
>   mai 21, 2018 6:26:54 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
>   INFORMAÇÕES: validateJarFile(C:\Users\Tiago\workspaceTiago.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ribeiraoreefshop\WEB-INF\lib\jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Alpha1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
>   mai 21, 2018 6:27:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
>   GRAVE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ribeiraoreefshop]]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1700)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1690)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ribeiraoreefshop]]
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
>       ... 6 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/weld/util/Consumer
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:267)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:417)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:890)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5527)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>       ... 6 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.weld.util.Consumer
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1907)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1750)
>       ... 20 more
>
> mai 21, 2018 6:27:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase
>   startInternal GRAVE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:758)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:705)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1700)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1690)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1247)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     ... 6 more
>
> mai 21, 2018 6:27:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>   GRAVE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is
>   unable to start. org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to
>   start component [StandardServer[8005]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:705)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardService[Catalina]]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:758)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     ... 7 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child
>   container failed during start     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1247)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     ... 11 more
>
> mai 21, 2018 6:27:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
>   INFORMAÇÕES: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] mai 21, 2018
>   6:27:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause INFORMAÇÕES:
>   Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] mai 21, 2018 6:27:05 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal INFORMAÇÕES:
>   Stopping service Catalina mai 21, 2018 6:27:05 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy INFORMAÇÕES: Destroying
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] mai 21, 2018 6:27:05 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy INFORMAÇÕES: Destroying
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]

Já tentei as soluções implementadas na internet e nenhuma funcionou. O que pode estar ocorrendo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução encontrada foi:
1º - Criar a classe `JPAUtil` para criar a `EntityManager`

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class JPAUtil {

      private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence
        .createEntityManagerFactory("postgreSQL");


      public JPAUtil() {

      }

      @Produces
      @RequestScoped
      public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
          return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
      }

      public void close(@Disposes EntityManager em) {
          em.close();
      }

}
```

2º - Mapear a classe `JPAUtil.java` no `beans.xml` na seguinte forma no atributo `bean-discovery-mode`:

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">
```

Porém a anotação `@ApplicationScoped` já faz esse mapeamento.